# dplyr case_when statement with list of characters

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list with 31 site names.

```
> typeof(Asites)
[1] "list"
> str(Asites)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   31 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Asites: chr  "45.88:-64.35" "45.88:-64.37" "45.89:-64.33" "45.89:-64.34" ...
```

I would like to write a case_when statement to change the name of all of those sites to the same value in my dataframe.  However, because the information is stored in a list, I get the following error message:

```
df %>%
  mutate(site2 = case_when(site %in% Asites ~ "A", 
                           TRUE ~ "B"))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types.
```

How can I change Asites so that this works?

EDIT (1/25/18):

Since I have over 9 million observations in my df, I've just provided dput for df$site and Asites.

```
dput(df$site[1:1000])
c("BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", "BennettMeadow", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.9:-64.36", "45.9:-64.36", 
"45.9:-64.36", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.35", "45.91:-64.35", "45.91:-64.35", 
"45.91:-64.35", "45.91:-64.35", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.9:-64.32", "45.9:-64.32", "45.89:-64.33", 
"45.89:-64.33", "45.89:-64.33", "45.89:-64.33", "45.89:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.35", "45.91:-64.35", "45.91:-64.35", "45.91:-64.35", 
"45.91:-64.35", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.34", 
"45.89:-64.34", "45.9:-64.32", "45.9:-64.32", "45.89:-64.33", 
"45.89:-64.33", "45.89:-64.33", "45.89:-64.33", "45.89:-64.33", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", "NA:NA", 
"NA:NA", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.92:-64.33", "45.92:-64.33", "45.92:-64.33", "45.92:-64.33", 
"45.92:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.92:-64.33", 
"45.92:-64.33", "45.92:-64.33", "45.92:-64.33", "45.92:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", 
"45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", 
"45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", 
"45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", 
"45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", 
"45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.33", 
"45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", 
"45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", 
"45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", 
"45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", 
"45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.33", 
"45.9:-64.33")

dput(Asites)
structure(list(recvDeployName = c("45.88:-64.35", "45.88:-64.37", 
"45.89:-64.33", "45.89:-64.34", "45.89:-64.35", "45.89:-64.36", 
"45.9:-64.32", "45.9:-64.33", "45.9:-64.34", "45.9:-64.35", "45.9:-64.36", 
"45.9:-64.37", "45.91:-64.32", "45.91:-64.33", "45.91:-64.34", 
"45.91:-64.35", "45.91:-64.36", "45.92:-64.33", "45.92:-64.34", 
"45.92:-64.35", "Bridge St Sackville (SHEEP)", "COLONY", "COLONY1 ", 
"COLONY2", "COLONY2", "DIKES", "HWY", "LOWERW", "RCI Sackville", 
"Sackville Eng", "SCHOOL", "SE", "SE")), row.names = c(NA, -33L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `unlist(Asites)`?

Comment: @Nate, thanks for that thought.  unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Comment: `mutate(df, site2 = case_when(site %in% Asites$Asites ~ "A", TRUE ~ "B"))`?

Comment: Can you post the data you are using using the dput function? dput(df) and dput(Asites) will create the code needed to reproduce those objects.

Comment: Thanks @avid_useR. unfortunately, I still get the same error message.

Comment: Thanks @DavidRosenman.  I've added the dput info above.  My df has over 9 million observations, so I've just provided the first 1000.  I hope that will be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I was trying to communicate yesterday:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(site2 = case_when(site %in% unlist(Asites) ~ "A", 
                           TRUE ~ "B")) %>%
  with(table(site2)) # just to show the breakdown of site2's contents, you'd drop this line IRL

# result
site2
A   B 
792 208
```

It seems to work for me using `dplyr_0.7.8`.

This strategy only works when the reference data frame,`Asites`, has only location values. If the reference data frame has more than just locations you would want to use the `Asites$recvDeployName` reference (like avid_useR suggests) to test against only a specific column.